# Is it correct to have a variable with the same name as a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, identifier

Is it correct to do this? :

```
namespace name {
    int name;
}

void proc(int name)
{
    name::name = name;
}

int main()
{
    int name = name::name;   
    return 0;
}
```

It works in GCC. But is this OK with standard and other compilers?

Comment: Correct?  Sure.  Easy to understand?  I'd say not.  Those `name::name = name` and `name = name::name` lines makes me cringe.

Comment: @Proxy: It makes more sense when it's in a function called `name()` returning a `struct name`. You avoid spelling errors by reducing the number of unique spellings in your source code. The same way Python reduces the amount of type errors.

Comment: @KerrekSB Does Python reduce the amount of type errors?  In my experience, it only moves the detection of such errors from compile time to runtime.

Comment: @KerrekSB And you definitely do not want to have a function and a type with the same name.  You have to know whether a symbol names a type or something else in order to parse C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is okay, we need to look at how the *scope resolution operator* works in this context. If we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `3.4.3` *Qualified name lookup* actually has a very similar example, it says (*emphasis mine*):

> If a :: scope resolution operator in a nested-name-specifier is not preceded by a decltype-specifier, **lookup of the name preceding that :: considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types**. If the name found does not designate a namespace or a class, enumeration, or dependent type, the program is ill-formed.[ Example:

```
class A {
public:
    static int n;
};

int main() {
    int A;
    A::n = 42; // OK
    A b; // ill-formed: A does not name a type
}
```

> —end example ]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to do that.
Namespaces are literally designed to resolve this kind of issue once the size of the code/project grows larger.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) is a good place to check things out about C++.

Comment: No, the [community consensus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194788/links-being-changed-to-cppreference-com) is that cplusplus.com is not a good reference while [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is.